# Extracting comments out of column with ratings

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
import pandas as pd

survey = [('How much do you like apples?', 4),
         ('How much do you like oranges?', 5),
         ('How much do like bananas?', 5),
         ('Why do you like fruits?', "They are the best")]
labels = ['Question', 'Answer']

before= pd.DataFrame.from_records(survey, columns=labels)
```

Should look like this:

```
survey = [('How much do you like apples?', 4, "NaN"),
         ('How much do you like oranges?', 5, "NaN"),
         ('How much do like bananas?', 5, "NaN"),
         ('Why do you like fruits?',"NaN", "They are the best")]
labels = ['Question', 'Answer', 'Comments']

after= pd.DataFrame.from_records(survey, columns=labels)
```

I'm working with a large dataset of survey responses. The problem I'm having is that under the answer column, responses are either 1-5, or a comment (string). I'm trying to break up this column into an Answer column that contains only continuous data (1-5), and another that contains only comments (strings). These new columns need to be formed in the current df. Would anyone know a function to help me get started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `to_numeric`

```
s=pd.to_numeric(before.Answer,errors='coerce')
before['Comments']=before.Answer.where(s.isnull())
before['Answer']=s
```

---

Output

```
before
Out[199]: 
                        Question  Answer           Comments
0   How much do you like apples?     4.0                NaN
1  How much do you like oranges?     5.0                NaN
2      How much do like bananas?     5.0                NaN
3        Why do you like fruits?     NaN  They are the best
```